# CSS z-index not working on absolute div child

Tags: html, css

I am making a graph using CSS, Its almost done but I am stuck with z-index for a div with class `graph-info`, Its hiding behind other graph bar.

HTML

```
            <div id="graph">
            <li>
                <div class="graph-info">
                    <h4>23 June 2015</h4>
                </div><!--end of graph-info-->
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="graph-info">
                   <h4>23 June 2015</h4>
                </div><!--end of graph-info-->
            </li>                
            <li>
                <div class="graph-info">
                    <h4>23 June 2015</h4>
                </div><!--end of graph-info-->
            </li>                
            <li>
                <div class="graph-info">
                    <h4>23 June 2015</h4>
                </div><!--end of graph-info-->
            </li>                
            <li>
                <div class="graph-info">
                    <h4>23 June 2015</h4>
                </div><!--end of graph-info-->
            </li>                   
            </div><!--end of graph-->
```

CSS

```
#graph{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:728px;
    height:auto;
    background:#666;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;    
}
#graph li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px 10px;
    padding:0px;
    width:20px;
    height:200px;
    background:#eee;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    z-index:1 !important;
}
#graph li:last-child{
 height:240px;
}
#graph li:nth-child(2) {
 height:230px;
}
#graph li .graph-info{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:#ccc;
    z-index:2 !important;
}
#graph li .graph-info h4{
    display:block;     
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    font:bold 12px/12px Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    border:none;
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding:0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kz4a3jv/)

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/7kz4a3jv/2/

Comment: but text will overlap..

Comment: or use this one https://jsfiddle.net/7kz4a3jv/3/

Comment: @Leothelion Thanks,  I'll use first one but the graph-info div is still behind bar

Comment: Check third one as in first i have used z-index on  h4 but in 3rd comment i have used z-index on div too so div will come above the graph.

Comment: @Leothelion, yes but it now hide behind other graph-info div, But I can work with it now thanks.

Comment: Ohh ok..Have a Nice Day :)

Comment: Thanks, Have a nice day :)